# How do I create a staging and production environment for the data within a database? Database/API/application architecture planning

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, architecture, system-design

I have two applications that will be going through my API and interacting with my database(s).

The first application displays production data that the customer can view, this has been through a QA process in a staging environment.

The second application is a CMS that the internal team can create, edit or delete data from.  Then they can view a preview of this data in their version of the first application.  Once they are happy with it they can push the data to production for a customer to view.

I have considered a couple of approaches.

What are insights?

What haven't I considered?

What approach achieves this functionality?

There are lots of relationships between the entities within the database which seems to complicate things whenever I try to get into the details of each approach.

**Potential Approach: Separate Databases**
I considered a separate database for staging and production but this has the downside of downtime when the changes need to be made.  Since the customer application is used internationally and changes can be expected to be made quite regularly the amount of downtime this would require isn't ideal.

**Potential Approach: Version Control (git style)**
A version control system within a single database using draft/version tables solves some issues but introduces problems with relationships as it is hard to keep track of join tables.  If we only needed to make edits to a single entity then this would be a good solution.

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? What published DB design textbook/reference are you following? What method? Where is the 1st place you are stuck? Why/how are you stuck? You essentially ask us to (re)write a textbook for an unidentified method & bespoke tutorial with no details on what you misunderstand or do or don't understand. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [“Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Answer (score 0):

Some common options:

1. Create an external representation of this database (JSON, XML, BSON, etc), write an exporter to dump the data out and an importer to pull it back in (this has the nice side-benefit of creating an "approved" representation that you can do things like roll back to.
2. Use an ETL tool to push the data to production using direct deletes/inserts or upserts if you are fancy about it (but you can screw this up pretty easily)
3. Good old backup/restore.  Downtime can often be avoided using things like read replicas that can be aged out as users migrate to the new instance.